# Which model to select if paired-t-test do not show significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, model-selection, paired-data

I have two classifiers: A and B. I have run 10-fold-cross-validation for both classifiers. A has better mean accuracy than B. Here are the scores:

**A**: [0.82, 0.9, 0.88, 0.86, 0.88, 0.92, 0.84, 0.98, 0.88, 0.90], mean: 0.886, median = 0.88, max = 0.98, min = 0.82
**B**: [0.86, 0.88, 0.88, 0.86, 0.84, 0.86, 0.9, 0.92, 0.88, 0.88], mean: 0.876, median = 0.88, max = 0.92, min = 0.84

Both classifiers passed Normality Test (Shapiro-Wilk Test). However, there is no statistical significance via paired-t-test (p = 0.44 >> 0.05). Should I select A because has better mean score, same median and better max score than B ? Should I do another statistical test ?